# Format textbox in VBA Userform to force + or - sign

Tags: vba, textbox, format, decimal, userform

I am working on a userform with different textboxes, they can contain only decimal numbers and must have either a plus or minus sign at the beggining, e.g:

+1.25 or
-0.75 or
-2.25

I can´t figure out what would be the correct format for the textbox, and how to force the user to input + or - sign before the numbers. So far I have this:

```
    Private Sub mytb_Change()
    '   Check if content is valid
    If Left(Me.mytb.value, 1) = "+" Or Left(Me.mytb.value, 1) = "-" Then
        Me.mytb.value = Format(Me.mytb.value, "+0.##;-0.##")
    Else
        MsgBox "Text must include + ó -", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Invalid data"
    '   Select textbox content
        With Me.mytb
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
    End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mytb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
            Case vbKeySubtract
            Case Asc("-")
            Case vbKeyAdd
            Case Asc("+")
            Case vbKeyDecimal
            Case vbKeyDelete
            Case vbKeyBack
            Case vbKeyReturn
            Case Else
                KeyAscii = 0
                Beep
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Problem one: Initial requirement to input signs before the number can still be bypassed after the message box alert (if clicking another textbox or hitting tab key)

Problem two: If I wanted to input -0.25 as soon as zero is typed the - sign turns into a plus sign.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE-
Some "fix" for the sign requirement to work properly, format problem persists...

```
Private Sub mytb_Change()
'   Check if content is valid
If Left(mytb.value, 1) = "+" Or Left(mytb.value, 1) = "-" Or mytb.value = "" Then
'do nothing
Else
   MsgBox "Text must include + ó -", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Invalid data"
'   Select textbox content
    With mytb
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        .SelText = ""
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are making your life too difficult.  Gather the input as a string.  If the string is acceptable then convert to a number if that's what you need.

Comment: You can also just assume that the absence of a sign implies a positive number, then in your value check, re-write the value with the "+" prepended to it.

Comment: Allright guys, thanks for the insights. basically I really need the user to type in that format because they tend to forget about doing it and this can cause problems later on. (for context: this userform is for an optometrist to organize his patients formulas/prescriptions more accurately)

Comment: @Hellzing personally I would put the `+` or `-` in a separate field, perhaps a `combobox` or group of option buttons and have it's own validation requirment to be selected (one or the other) that way the user will need to actually choose one rather than rely on them to type it into the box along with you can concatenate after the fact. Remove the

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Samuel, I have slightly modifed my code in order for the requirement to work better (sort of) but I still don´t know what would be the correct format to allow only 2 decimals. I´ll post the code but leave the question open in case someone has sometinhg to add :)